# Does the kotlinx-coroutines-android dependency come with everything in kotlinx-coroutines-core?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-coroutines

I'm looking at the [Coroutines library on github](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) and it mentions needing to add the `kotlinx-coroutines-core` as a dependency to enable coroutines and that I could also "add other modules", so I'm not really sure if these two are necessary to run Coroutines on Android or just adding `kotlinx-coroutines-android` would be enough.

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.3")
}
```

I know that you need `kotlinx-coroutines-android` for the Main thread dispatcher, I'm just not sure if it's a transitive dependency that also contains the core library within it as well, I don't want to have both clogging build time by downloading an extra unnecessary library.

Comment: You can remove `kotlinx-coroutines-core` or `kotlinx-coroutines-android` from the dependencies, clean and run a project, if it builds and works correctly, then you don't need it. You can include only `kotlinx-coroutines-android`, it should have all you need to work with coroutines, even Main thread dispatcher.

Comment: yes everything required for android

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you only need:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'
}
```

The source for the above is the official Android docs about coroutines:
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines

Answer (score 2):

1. implementation
   "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4":

This dependency includes the core Kotlin coroutines library along with Android-specific extensions. It's the most common choice for Android app development. It provides additional utilities and integration with Android's UI thread (the main thread) to make it easier to work with coroutines in an Android app. You should use this dependency in most cases when working with Android.

2. implementation
   "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4":

This dependency includes only the core Kotlin coroutines library without the Android-specific extensions. It's useful in non-Android Kotlin projects, such as server-side Kotlin applications or Kotlin multi-platform projects that target platforms other than Android. If you're not developing an Android app, you can use this core dependency.

Thus coroutines can fully work with "kotlinx-coroutines-android".

Answer (score 0):

you must add this dependency when you want add coroutine in your project `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3`
this dependecy provide everything related to coroutine and flow

now if you working with Android you must add this dependency to

```
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3
```

as the document says :
This gives you access to the Android Dispatchers.Main coroutine dispatcher and also makes sure that in case of a crashed coroutine with an unhandled exception that this exception is logged before crashing the Android application, similarly to the way uncaught exceptions in threads are handled by the Android runtime.

reference link :
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines